# docker container down after yum cron updates containerd.io

Tags: docker, cron

At my centOs7 server, yum-cron is installed to update software automatically.

I excluded docker update because if yum-cron update docker, my docker containers are all down.

Even though I excluded docker update, my docker containers are down except some container which
is registered as servcie.

I saw logs at var/log/yum.log and found some software is updated named containerd.io.

Is there any way to make docker containers never down after yum cron update containerd.io?

There is restart option in my docker-compose.yml.

below is my yun-cron.conf

```
[base]

exclude = docker*
# This section overrides yum.conf

# Use this to filter Yum core messages
# -4: critical
# -3: critical+errors
# -2: critical+errors+warnings (default)
```

and below is /var/log/yum.log | grep -i updated

```
...
May 28 09:33:51 Updated: containerd.io.x86_64 1.4.6-3.1.el7
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Maybe when your `docker` service gets restarted, your containers go down. Run `systemctl status docker` to see the uptime if it's been restarted. Then run `docker logs CONTAINER` in which `CONTAINER` could be the name of one of your containers to see if you can find anything

Comment: You should set the `restart` option in the `docker-compose.yml` to `always`. If the docker deamon is killed (which also happens at shutdown) your containers will automatically come up again when the docker deamon starts.